# No title in a CustomDialog exception

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to delete the title from a `Dialog` with `requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in the `onCreate` method, but it doesn't work since it gives the exception:

```
06-19 09:35:00.319: E/AndroidRuntime(5071): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

I have the `requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before the content, like in the following:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.leesmeerdialog_layout);
        ...
}
```

I also tried with but still no luck

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.leesmeerdialog_layout);
            ...
    }
```

When calling the dialog with the `show()` method is where the exception pops up:

```
mLeesMeer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDialog = new LeesMeerDialog(getActivity(), mDescription, new OnReadyListener());
                mDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

I already did this in dialogs in my code and never had a problem, but I can't figure out the problem with this one, so any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: problem must me here getActivity() replace this with yourclassname.this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it calling the `mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` where the `CustomDialog` was going to be shown:

```
mDialog = new CustomDialog(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.ervaringen_post_msg), new OnReadyListener());
                mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog_layout);
                mDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.leesmeerdialog_layout);
        ...
}
```

Comment: onemore way is to add in android manifest        <activity
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

Answer (score 0):

Use this to hide title in Dialogs.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be because you are calling

```
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog_layout);
```

before calling `mDialog.show();`
The `onCreate` is called when you try to show the dialog

Comment: what i don't understand, which one is tha layout (R.layout.customdialog_layout) or (R.layout.leesmeerdialog_layout)?